# Register a user for my site in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, registration

I am trying to register a user in my cakePHP project. I completed a login&registration tutorial which worked perfectly. I have since tried to reuse the code in my project but i am having no luck. The login part is working great but the registration is failing every time. Any help would be great.

my register function in AdminController.php

```
public function register(){
    $user = $this->Admin->newEntity();
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $user = $this->Admin->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if($this->Admin->save($user)){
            $this->Flash->success('You are registered');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('You have not registered');
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

my Admin/register.ctp

```
<br>
<div class = "index large-4 medium-4 large-offset-4 medium-offset-4">
    <div class = "panel">
        <h2 class = "text-centre">Please Register</h2>
        <?= $this->form->create($user); ?>
            <?= $this ->form->input('first name'); ?>
            <?= $this ->form->input('last name'); ?>
            <?= $this ->form->input('date of birth', array('type' => 'date')); ?>
            <?= $this ->form->input('email'); ?>
            <?= $this ->form->input('password', array('type' => 'password')); ?>
            <?= $this ->form->submit('register', array('class' => 'button')); ?>
        <?= $this->form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

my table i want to register my users in

```
CREATE TABLE `admin` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`lName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`dOb` date NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`modified` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is AdminTable.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
* Admin Model
*
* @method \App\Model\Entity\Admin get($primaryKey, $options = [])
* @method \App\Model\Entity\Admin newEntity($data = null, array     $options = [])
* @method \App\Model\Entity\Admin[] newEntities(array $data, array   $options = [])
* @method \App\Model\Entity\Admin|bool     save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
* @method \App\Model\Entity\Admin   patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array   $options = [])
* @method \App\Model\Entity\Admin[] patchEntities($entities, array   $data, array $options = [])
* @method \App\Model\Entity\Admin findOrCreate($search, callable   $callback = null)
*
* @mixin \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TimestampBehavior
*/
class AdminTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('admin');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
}

/**
 * Default validation rules.
 *
 * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
 * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create')
        ->add('id', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider'   => 'table']);

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('fName', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('fName');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('lName', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('lName');

    $validator
        ->date('dOb')
        ->requirePresence('dOb', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('dOb');

    $validator
        ->email('email')
        ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('email');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('password');

    return $validator;
}

/**
 * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
 * application integrity.
 *
 * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
 * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
 */
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['id']));

    return $rules;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for taking the time to look through this.

Thank you for the help. After adding the code to debug i get the error:

```
[
'fName' => [
    '_required' => 'This field is required'
],
'lName' => [
    '_required' => 'This field is required'
]
]
```

Comment: Can you be so kind to provide the details of your error?

Comment: Because of this code `$this->Flash->error('You have not registered');` The only error i get is **You have not registered**. Is there anyway i can find out what the reason for the error is?

Comment: Can you share the `AdminTable.php` because of the validation it will not save the data.

Comment: @AmanRawat i have included the file you have asked for. Thank you

Comment: Come on, guys, do you find it difficult to read the documentation and tutorials?  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html and http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED

From reading the cakePHP cook book i found that i had not conformed to the strict naming conventions which cakePHP needs to work correctly. As a result of my Admin table column names not being the correct format it was unable to pass data successfully. I change my column names from the format `fName` to `first_name`. I then changed the table name from `Admin` to `Admins`. Lastly i issued the command `bin/cake bake all admins`. I can now successfully register and login. Thanks for all you help guys.